# Using LLVM to optimize programs that use large structs

Tags: optimization, llvm

I made a toy Brainfuck compiler. It works, but given the known initial state, the output is far less optimized than I hoped.

I have this state structure:

```
struct state {
    unsigned char mem[0x1000];
    unsigned long ip;
    unsigned index;
};
```

The state structure (which looks like `type { [4096 x i8], i64, i32 }` in LLVM IR) is allocated with an `alloca` instruction, and then zeroed with a `memset` call (the intrinsic version).

And my operations are implemented as you would expect:

- `<` as `state.index--`
- `>` as `state.index++`
- `-` as `state.mem[state.index]--`
- `+` as `state.mem[state.index]++`
- `.` as `putchar(state.mem[state.index])`
- `,` as `state.mem[state.index] = getchar()`
- `[` as the beginning of a `while (state.mem[state.index] != 0) {` loop
- `]` as the end of a loop

For each operation, I emit the simplest matching LLVM IR I can think of. For instance, `+` is implemented as:

```
; %index = &state.index
  %index = getelementptr inbounds %"state", %"state"* %state, i64 0, i32 1

; %0 = *%index
  %0 = load i64, i64* %index, align 8

; %arrayidx = &state.mem[%0]
  %arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds %"state", %"state"* %state, i64 0, i32 0, i64 %0

; %1 = *%arrayidx
  %1 = load i8, i8* %arrayidx, align 1

; %inc = %1 + 1
  %inc = add i8 %1, 1

; *arrayidx = %inc
  store i8 %inc, i8* %arrayidx, align 1
```

I thought that this would be enough information to let LLVM optimize programs so hard that there would barely be anything left. The initial state is known, no pointer to it is shared, and sequential increments are easy to detect. Obviously, loops are harder to optimize, but I could understand that.

Much to my disappointment, however, the resulting code is still an ugly mess of `getelementptr`, `load` and `store`. None of these were elided in favor of something simpler.

I wasn't sure if I was just doing something wrong, so I took a hello world program and converted it to C by basically replacing each Brainfuck character by its matching C code as shown above, compiled it with Clang on `O3` and dumped the resulting IR, and found it to be vastly equivalent. It appears that Clang isn't any more able to cope with this than my poor toy compiler.

However, if I take `index` off the struct and make it a local, Clang is able to optimize most of its uses into IR registers. So what's the deal here? Why is LLVM not able to optimize patterns of access to a struct? Is there a way I can tell LLVM that this memory is 100% private and that it can optimize its uses any way it wants?

If this makes an important difference, I'm LLVM 3.7 svn, up to date as of sometime last week.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're not providing a data layout string. Without this many optimizers are unable to produce decent results - they cannot know the size of the pointer, etc.

See http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout for more information. I would suggest to grab the data layout string as generated by clang on your platform and paste into .ll as the first step.

Comment: I turned the whole thing into a C program, compiled it through Clang (and let it decide the datalayout), and basically got the same result.